# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded from unknown reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

A little intro: I actually got the problem fixed as of writing this, now I would just want to know, why it was there in the first place:

I'm trying to retrieve data from mongoDB with mongoose. The code works without problems 99% and for some reason only finding data from certain table WITH certain function causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"-error.

Now I have jasmine tests which should confirm that the datalayerdatas-table works fine, but when it retrieves the data through getData.js, it throws the error.

Code in stack-order.

gameData-spec.js (jasmine spec):

```
   getData.getDataLayer(dataToFind)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("DATA getDataLayer", data[0]);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.log("Error in finding dataLayerData", e.stack);
    });
```

getData.js (proxy / API functionality to get the data):

```
ret.getDataLayer = function getData(data) {
   console.log(666)
   return getData(dataLayerData.getDataByPlayer, {gameID: data.gameID, playerID: data.playerID, turnID: data.turnID});
};

function getData (DBfunc, data) {
    var promise = DBfunc(data);

    return promise;
}
```

gameData.js (retrieves data from mongoDB):

dataLayerData: (function dataLayerData () {
      var ret = {};

```
  ret.insert = function (data) {
      return insertData( models.dataLayerData, data);
  };

  ret.getDataByPlayer = function (data) {
      var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
      return getData( models.dataLayerData, { gameID: ObjectId(String(data.gameID)), playerID: data.playerID, turnID: data.turnID } );
  };
  return ret;
})()
```

For the other tables I didn't even need the mong.Schema.Types.ObjectId-specification, when finding data, but I tried it with this one, didn't have any effect though (basically I need it when manually doing mongoDB from command line so I assume I would need it here too).

Also the mongoDB Schema:

```
var dataLayerData = new mong.Schema({
     "playerID": Number,
     "gameID": mong.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     "turnID": Number,
     "objects": [
        {
           "dataName": String,
           "dataType": String,
           "objects": {
           }
        }
     ]
});
```

Now as said, there are other tables being retrieved exactly the same way and they work. Even if I replace the gameData-spec.js.call with some other database-find, it works without problems. I do not see why it even gets into a callback-loop and how.

For debugging and clearing the problem I set the console.log(666) to getData.js and it keeps spamming the console for a while. So for some reason it seems that function gets called over and over.

Later on I noticed that the getData call was unnecessary (that is a stripped down version). Why does just that call in between cause a maximum call stack error?

Comment: It seems `getData` inside `getDataLayer` is not `getData` defined below, is actually the `getData` function callee above, used for recursion. Is this intentionally? Recursion can cause overflow in JS.

Comment: No that is not intentional, that's naturally the reason. Thank you for clearing that to me! That would have been counted as an correct answer too. Unfortunately I get very tunnel-sighted when I debug my own code for a long time.

I usually don't like anonymous functions for debugging purposes, but I guess I start thinking otherwise now :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getData` inside `getDataLayer` is not the `getData` function defined below, is actually the `getData` function callee above, used for recursion. Recursion can cause overflow in JavaScript.

```
               // fixed ---v---
ret.getDataLayer = function(data) {
   console.log(666)
   return getData(dataLayerData.getDataByPlayer, {gameID: data.gameID, playerID: data.playerID, turnID: data.turnID});
};
```